# How to use two titles in Ionic header?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In ionic, I need to use 'Heading'(Large one) and 'Sub-heading'(smaller one). I am using like following,

```
<ion-view view-title="Primary Heading">
    <ion-content>.....</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This is working. But, I need to use two headings. One as 'Primary heading' and another one as 'Sub-heading'. I tried to use 'header-bar', 'sub-header-bar'. But, it is not working as I expected. Heading should be in first line and sub-heading should be in next line. I also tried with

```
 <ion-nav-title>...</ion-nav-title>
```

So, how to achieve this one. And also I have to apply my own styling for Headings. Please, help me out.

Comment: http://codepen.io/danbhala/pen/ChIEt

Comment: Not like this. The 'heading' and 'sub-heading' in same Header-bar.. The example you have given is using two header-bars.

Answer (score 5):

After trying out, My answer for my question is,

```
 <ion-view> 
    <ion-nav-title>
        <div class="page-title">HEADING</div>
        <div class="page-sub-title">Sub Heading</div>
    </ion-nav-title>
    <ion-content>.....</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And to apply style, my CSS would be like this,

```
.page-title{
         margin-top : -10px;
         color: #ffffff;
         font-size: 1.5em;
}
.page-sub-title{
         margin-top: - 25px;
         color: green;
         font-size : .9em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a tab solution with subheader. The first header is set by the `<ion-view>` as you mentioned. The subheader can be set with `<ion-header>`.

```
<ion-view title="Primary Heading">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader">
        <h1 class="title">Subheader</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        CONTENT
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

See next CodePen: http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/keHnw

Comment: nope.. not like this.. anyway, I tried out with this.. and found my required answer... I post my answer below...

Answer (score 1):

This is the very basic CSS and Html code use this

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>     
    <ion-title>Title
        <p class="subtitle">Subtitle </p>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.toolbar-title {
        overflow: visible;
        position: relative;
        .subtitle {
          position: absolute;
          top: 6px;
          font-size: 66%;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made in this way:

```
.page-title {
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 36px;
}

.page-sub-title {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #459691;
}
```

For example.